# Coderpad's new C++ example is cryptic: meaning of `auto` and `const char* const&`

Tags: c++, reference

Two questions about the code below:

1. What is the type of the variable `words` in `auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };`?
2. What are the types of the variable `word` in the various `for` loops?

Coderpad's (an online coding tool used to write code live in front of an interviewer--test it yourself at https://app.coderpad.io/sandbox and then select the language at the left) default C++ example used to be this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// To execute C++, please define "int main()"
int main() {
  auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
  for (const string& word : words) {
    cout << word;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It's output is:

> Hello, World!

The meaning of `auto` is pretty complicated there. `words` is of type `std::initializer_list<std::string>` (right?--I mean, doing the replacement just below does run), so you can do this:

```cpp
// replace this
auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };

// with this
std::initializer_list<std::string> words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
```

This is why I hate `auto` so much. I think this Coderpad example is terrible.

Well, it just got worse. Their new C++ example within the last several months is now:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// To execute C++, please define "int main()"
int main() {
  auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
  for (const char* const& word : words) {
    cout << word;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The type of `words` now seems to be `std::initializer_list<const char*>`, right? That runs.

But, what the heck is `const char* const&` in the `for` loop? I'm not familiar with this. The website https://cdecl.org/, the common-person's translator of "C gibberish" to "English", says that `const char* const& word` means:

> declare word as reference to const pointer to const char

I guess that makes sense. But, why a reference to a const pointer to const char instead of just a pointer to a const char?

Using `for (const char* word : words) {` instead of `for (const char* const& word : words) {` seems to work just fine too, and is much simpler.

Here's my final, more-explicit version which runs just fine too:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// To execute C++, please define "int main()"
int main() {
  std::initializer_list<const char*> words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
  for (const char* word : words) {
    std::cout << word;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<sub>Note: Coderpad is a shared coding interview tool I type into when taking or giving an interview. It's not for learning; it's for interviewing. It shares the coding screen so two people can see the same code while interviewing remotely over a Zoom chat or phone call.</sub>

Comment: _"`words` is of type `std::initializer_list<std::string>`"_ that is not correct.  `words` has type `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, using that as the type runs. Can you expound upon it? What type is it then? I'm sure I've got multiple things wrong here, hence my question.

Comment: @DrewDormann, this is why I hate `auto` so much. I think this coderpad example is terrible.

Comment: To get the actual type from the compiler, add the line `struct {} words2 = words;`, and look at the error message: `error: conversion from ‘std::initializer_list<const char*>’ to non-scalar type ‘main()::<unnamed struct>’ requested`. So the actual type is `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

Comment: You're main problem is that it isn't using auto enough ;) `auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" }; for (const auto& word : words) cout << word;`.  Seriously though, what is the actual question?  If it's why they chose they type they did, well you'd have to ask them.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if I do `for (const auto& word : words)`, what is the type of `word`? Is it `const char* const&`? And, if I do `for (const auto word : words)`, what is the type of `word`? Is it `const char*`? Is there any advantage of the const reference version over the copy of a pointer version?

Comment: Take a look at the very useful C++ insights website for these kinds of questions: https://cppinsights.io/s/5d143229

Comment: What are you complaining about? that the C++ type system is too complicated or that when you investigate you don't understand it? Work with it as a black box or be open to learning. After all, this also works, and you don't _need_ to know anything about all this: `for (auto const& word : { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" }) {... }`. I agree that the particular code you show can lead to confusion, it probably wouldn't even pass code review of clang-tidy. C++ code in the wild is usually bad, that includes books also.

Comment: @alfC, that's insightful. Thanks. I'm just trying to understand. I suppose when I feel frustrated about trying to understand, I come across like I'm complaining? I don't like working with things as a black box, but I suppose that's what many do? As for myself, I am open to learning. Did anything I say in my question, comments, or anywhere else indicate otherwise?

Comment: @chris_se, that site is amazing! Thank you! Never heard of it before!

Comment: @GabrielStaples The type will be a reference to a `const` whatever element type `words` has.   In this case `const auto&` would be `const char* const&` and `const auto` would be `const char* const`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, understood, no problem. If you want to understand, my recommendation is to use better tools. Maybe less flashy tools. See my answer.

Comment: @alfC, what do you mean by less-flashy tools? Coderpad is a shared coding interview tool I type into when taking or giving an interview. Is that the "flashy" tool you're referring to?

Comment: @GabrielStaples, by less flashy, I mean godbolt, or at least an online compiler that allows controlling compilation flags. See also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7Gv4J3FyYE " C++ Weekly - Ep 350 - The Right Way to Write C++ Code in 2022 "

Comment: I just checked and now the default C++ example, now reads `for (const char* const& word : words)`. Still not the best example, but it seems they took note! Good for them. https://app.coderpad.io/sandbox

Comment: @alfC, the fact that they updated their example to what you have is in my question. I said, "Well, it just got worse. Their new C++ example within the last several months is now:"...`for (const char* const& word : words) {`. Using a reference to a pointer isn't better in my opinion, it's worse. Using `for (const char* const word : words) {` would be better.

Comment: Arguably, even `for (const auto& word : words) {` is better (more-readable) than `for (const char* const& word : words)` so long as they make the declaration of `words` explicit: `std::initializer_list<const char*> words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };`. In my opinion, they took a bad (not very understandable) example and made it worse (even less-understandable). Update: actually, I could go either way on that since I like explicit. I just think it's weird to use a reference on a pointer. Just copy the pointer. `for (const char* const word : words) {` works just fine and is just as efficient.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, yes, still not the best code (the original was the worst IMO). I think their logic is that they wanted the examples in all languages to look the same, with dire results. Well, there you have, your first interview question: "fix coderpad default C++ example". (without compiler warnings). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with, looking at feedback thus far. My questions are:

1. **What is the type of the variable `words` in `auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };`?**

   The answer is `std::initializer_list<const char*>`

   [@pts has a great tip to figure this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656427/coderpads-new-c-example-is-cryptic-meaning-of-auto-and-const-char-const/75656629#comment133473115_75656427):

   > To get the actual type from the compiler, add the line `struct {} words2 = words;`, and look at the error message: `error: conversion from ‘std::initializer_list<const char*>’ to non-scalar type ‘main()::<unnamed struct>’ requested`. So the actual type is `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

   Here's a full example which does that:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>

   // To execute C++, please define "int main()"
   int main() {
     auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
     struct {} words2 = words;

     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. **What are the types of the variable `word` in the various `for` loops?**

   In `for (const string& word : words) {` it is `const string&`, so the `const char*` types are converted to `const string` references.

   In:

   ```cpp
   for (const char* const& word : words) {
   // and (same thing):
   for (const auto& word : words) {
   // and (same thing):
   for (auto const & word : words) {
   ```

   ...it is `const char* const&`, which is a `const char*` passed by const reference.

   There's no real advantage in this case over the following:

   ```cpp
   for (const char* word : words)
   // or (same thing):
   for (auto word : words)
   ```

   ...in which `word` is a `const char*`, passed by copy of a pointer (copying `const char*` pointer elements from the initializer list `words` to the variable `word`), since copying a pointer is as efficient as passing by C++ reference.

   As [pointed out by @chris_se in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656427/coderpads-new-c-example-is-cryptic-meaning-of-auto-and-const-char-const/75656629#comment133473370_75656629), however: this:

   ```cpp
   for (const auto word : words)
   // or (same thing):
   for (auto const word : words)
   // or (same thing, but explicit):
   for (const char* const word : words)
   ```

   ...is slightly different from just above, as the `const` here gets applied to the whole `auto` type, and the `auto` type is `const char*`, making the `const auto` or `auto const` type therefore `const char* const`, which makes the *pointer itself* also `const`, not just the contents it points to `const`. As @chris_se puts it:

   > With regards to the last code block you have: technically `for (const auto word : words)` will have a type `const char * const` instead of `const char*`. This means that with `for (const char* word : words)` you can let `word` point to a different C string within the for loop (`word = "Goodbyte!";`), but you can't do that with the `const auto word: words` variant, as the pointer itself is also `const` there.

   And [from @NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656427/coderpads-new-c-example-is-cryptic-meaning-of-auto-and-const-char-const/75656629#comment133473658_75656427) [edited for punctuation]:

   > [In `const auto& word : words`,] the type [of the variable `word`] will be a reference to a `const` <whatever element type `words` has>. In this case, `const auto&` would be `const char* const&`, and `const auto` would be `const char* const` [since the element type for elements in `words` is already `const char*`].

### Going further: understanding C++ gibberish and black boxes; gaining "insight" into C++ code expansion to see what the compiler sees

Also from @chris_se, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656427/coderpads-new-c-example-is-cryptic-meaning-of-auto-and-const-char-const/75656629#comment133473287_75656427):

> Take a look at the very useful C++ insights website for these kinds of questions: https://cppinsights.io/s/5d143229

Example source:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void a()
{
  auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
  for (auto const& word : words) {
    std::cout << word;
  }
}

void b()
{
  auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };
  for (auto const word : words) {
    std::cout << word;
  }
}

// To execute C++, please define "int main()"
int main() {
  a();
  b();
  return 0;
}
```

Example "insights" and code expansion provided by https://cppinsights.io/:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void a()
{
  std::initializer_list<const char *> words = std::initializer_list<const char *>{"Hello, ", "World!", "\n"};
  {
    std::initializer_list<const char *> & __range1 = words;
    const char *const * __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    const char *const * __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; __begin1 != __end1; ++__begin1) {
      const char *const & word = *__begin1;
      std::operator<<(std::cout, word);
    }
    
  }
}


void b()
{
  std::initializer_list<const char *> words = std::initializer_list<const char *>{"Hello, ", "World!", "\n"};
  {
    std::initializer_list<const char *> & __range1 = words;
    const char *const * __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    const char *const * __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; __begin1 != __end1; ++__begin1) {
      const char *const word = *__begin1;
      std::operator<<(std::cout, word);
    }
    
  }
}


// To execute C++, please define "int main()"
int main()
{
  a();
  b();
  return 0;
}
```

Their default example:

Source:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const char arr[10]{2,4,6,8};

    for(const char& c : arr)
    {
      printf("c=%c\n", c);
    }
}
```

Insight:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  const char arr[10] = {2, 4, 6, 8, '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
  {
    const char (&__range1)[10] = arr;
    const char * __begin1 = __range1;
    const char * __end1 = __range1 + 10L;
    for(; __begin1 != __end1; ++__begin1) {
      const char & c = *__begin1;
      printf("c=%c\n", static_cast<int>(c));
    }
    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With regards to the last code block you have: technically `for (const auto word : words)` will have a type `const char * const` instead of `const char*`. This means that with `for (const char* word : words)` you can let `word` point to a different C string within the for loop (`word = "Goodbyte!";`), but you can't do that with the `const auto word: words` variant, as the pointer itself is also `const` there.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion, it seems you are pointing out how the language interacts with users and vice versa more than any particular technical point.
For example, through these interactive sites.
I think many of these interactive sites bias the experience of learning.

I agree that the particular code you show can lead to confusion; it probably wouldn't even pass code review or linter analysis.
C++ code in the wild is usually bad, including books and snippets.

I could explain the origin of the confusion: strings in C++, initializer_list iteration, etc.
But I think a more proactive strategy is not buying into these easy-to-use tools online.
And instead, make an effort to find serious tools that help you with these easy-to-reach dark corners of the language.
Unfortunately, ["Fisher-Price"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Price)-type interfaces to "learn C++/Python/etc." do not offer these tools because they put ease of use first and correctness second.

These extra tools and configuration options are (unfortunately) fundamental to development.
I am talking about tools like `clang-tidy` and, at the least, controlling compiling flags. (`-Wall -Wextra`).

See what happens when I use flags that need to be active to compile any new project:

[image]

https://godbolt.org/z/x5da7rfEe

You will probably learn more from modern compiler warnings than any expert.
Also, this experts-friendly site has links to cppinsights, mentioned in the discussion (and benchmark tools).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by less-flashy tools, and "Fisher-Prize"-type interfaces? Coderpad is a shared coding interview tool I type into when taking or giving an interview. It's not for learning; it's for interviewing. It shares the coding screen so two people can see the same code while interviewing remotely over a Zoom chat or phone call. I have an upcoming interview using it, so I was looking at the interface.

Comment: Fished-Price (I spelled it wrong) is a UI design philosophy that prioritizes simplicity over control, to the extreme of giving the illusion of control rather than true control (green "Play" button?). I am not familiar with Coderpad. My first impression is not good. By trying to be uniform across languages it minimized the interface of C++ so you couldn't control very reasonable compiler flags. The fact that they vet poorly the code snippets as you pointed our also tells a lot. I don't care interviewers use it. A serious C++ interview would use Godbolt in my opinion, also usable with Zoom.