# Why can't auto infer the type when the return type is specified?

Tags: c++, type-inference, auto

MRE:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> someFunction() {
    auto vec;
    return vec;
}
```

What's stopping "auto" from inferring the type of `vec` as `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: The variable type must be known when you *define* it. When the compiler sees the definition, it doesn't know what the variable will be used for, so the type is unknown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In MSVC, the error states that it cannot "deduce" the type. I think its pretty deducible from the MRE, no? Is it so that the type by definition needs to be mentioned during the definition making something like this illegal, but something like `auto vec = { "abc","def" }` legal?

Comment: Your comment doesn't appear to comprehend the one you're responding to. Adding on to that, what do you think the type of `"abc"` is?

Comment: `"abc"` is a string, no?

Comment: If you mean `std::string`, then no. It's a `const char[4]`.

Comment: @NathanPierson, then what construct (forgive my terminology) will be inferred as `std::string`?

Comment: justanotherguy, I think you would have to explicitly use `auto vec = { std::string{"abc"}, std::string{"def"} };`, but even that is _not_ a vector! It is of type `std::initializer_list<std::string>`. To make it a vector you'd have to get even more explicit, and do this: `auto vec = std::vector<std::string>{"abc", "def"};`. But then that begs the question, why even use `auto`!? Instead, just do it the best way, with*out* `auto`: `std::vector<std::string> vec{"abc", "def"};`.

Comment: Personally, I *hate* `auto`. It obfuscates at every turn. I talk about that a bit in [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656629/4561887). The use of `auto` is a debated topic, however. Some people really love it. And...that's one of the reasons I don't want to work with those people. :) I'd rather go program in C than fight with a C++ developer about `auto`.

Comment: justanotherguy, to see how C++ sees your code, run it through https://cppinsights.io/. I've found this tool to be _amazing_ to help me better understand C++! I only recently found out about it about the time I wrote [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656629/4561887).

Comment: Referring to the start of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656629/4561887), I am reminded that `auto words = { "Hello, ", "World!", "\n" };` is of type `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

Comment: The way `auto` is specified is that it deduces the type of a variable based on how that variable is *initialised*.   So the only information considered in the line `auto vec` is the fact that no initialiser is provided.   Since there are many types that don't require initialisation, there is no information to infer the type of `vec`.   Now, sure, `auto` *could* be specified to look at the context in which the variable is subsequently used - but that would make the specification (in the standard) *and* implementation of compilers (to comply with such a specification) much more complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why can't `auto` infer the type when the return type is specified?

Because the C++ specification says it can't (see also the [answer by @Anya here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160425/4561887)). More specifically, the *people* who write the specification apparently *don't want* it to.

So, I'll just explain below how the compiler *actually* works, not how the compiler *should, might, or could* work. Languages like Rust, however, are very different, and [*can* do this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/types/inference.html). Thanks, @Blindy, [for pointing that out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160338/why-cant-auto-infer-the-type-when-the-return-type-is-specified/76160422?noredirect=1#comment134382386_76160422)

This is a good question.

---

From your question, it appears that you believe that since the compiler knows the return type, it should be able to deduce that the variable being returned *must* be of that return type. But, that is *not* how the C++ compiler works!

Rather, the compiler knows the return type, so it tries to implicitly cast `vec` *to* that known return type upon returning. *But*, it doesn't know how to perform this implicit cast because it doesn't know the original type of `vec`.

That's just how the compiler works. Specifying a return type doesn't change the type of `vec`, it just ensures that the compiler tries to implicitly cast `vec` *to* that type.

So, with your code, you get this error when compiled with the GNU g++ compiler as C++17:

```bash
main.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > someFunction()’:
main.cpp:15:5: error: declaration of ‘auto vec’ has no initializer
   15 |     auto vec;
      |     ^~~~
```

To make my point, check this out. This code *compiles*! I am *forcing* a reinterpret cast from an `int` to a `std::vector<std::string>`:

Run this code online here: https://onlinegdb.com/RaDEmExfF

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> someFunction() 
{
    int i = 0;

    // return by value (copy)
    return *((std::vector<std::string>*)(&i)); // C-style cast

    // OR (same thing)
    // return *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>*>(&i); // C++ cast
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vector = someFunction();
    
    return 0;
}
```

That makes no sense and is totally undefined behavior simply because `sizeof(int) < sizeof(std::vector<std::string>)`, however, meaning that the space allocated for the `int` is *too small* to contain the `std::vector<std::string>` object, so I get a run-time crash. Here is that run-time crash output on Linux x86-64:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length
```

Just remember, the return type doesn't *specify* the source type of `vec`. Rather, it simply enforces the type that `vec` gets *implicitly cast to* when it is returned.

#### Going further: memory pools

Note: the below memory pool demos are *not* a good use of memory pools in this case. They are just a demo to teach some interesting concepts that are useful in other scenarios, such as when implementing your own `malloc()` or `new` from scratch in a deterministic, O(1) sort of way, using memory pools (either statically-allocated, or dynamically-allocated at initialization), rather than relying on the built-in dynamic memory allocators which are *not* deterministic and *not* O(1) in time complexity.

Check this out. To make things even weirder for you, this is a totally fine and valid program now, with *well-defined* behavior.

I simply used an array of bytes as a memory pool to statically construct a `std::vector<std::string>` object from within a memory pool of 100 bytes. I could have used a memory pool of `int`s too, as `int[25]`.

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> someFunction() 
{
    constexpr uint16_t NUM_BYTES = 100;
    // undefined behavior check
    static_assert(NUM_BYTES >= sizeof(std::vector<std::string>));

    uint8_t memory_pool[NUM_BYTES];
    // set all bytes in the memory pool to zero
    memset(memory_pool, 0, sizeof(memory_pool)); 

    // return by value (copy)
    return *((std::vector<std::string>*)(memory_pool));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vector = someFunction();
    vector.push_back("hello ");
    vector.push_back("world");

    std::cout << vector[0] << vector[1] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Now it is a perfect program and runs just fine. The output is:

```
hello world
```

One more valid version of this function that now has optimal memory usage (just like the actual, proper way to do it below does):

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> someFunction() 
{
    uint8_t memory_pool[sizeof(std::vector<std::string>)];
    memset(memory_pool, 0, sizeof(memory_pool)); 
    
    // return by value (copy)
    return *((std::vector<std::string>*)(memory_pool));
}
```

Or, **just skip the memory pool and use the proper type in the first place** [<== key takeaway here--just do this!]:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> someFunction() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    
    return vec;
}
```

...but you can't use `auto` here:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> someFunction() 
{
    auto vec; // NOT ok!
    
    return vec;
}
```

Notes:

1. The returns of `std::vector<std::string>` *by copy* are probably triggering the compiler to make use of ["copy elision" and "return value optimization"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/4561887), which from what I understand basically just makes the compiler skip the copy and treat the original variable inside the function as though it was in a scope outside the function.
2. This:

   ```cpp
   std::cout << "sizeof(std::vector<std::string>) = " 
       << sizeof(std::vector<std::string>) << "\n";
   ```

   on my Linux x86-64 system with the `g++ -std=c++17` compiler outputs `sizeof(std::vector<std::string>) = 24`, meaning that a vector object of that type is 24 bytes. Therefore, any memory pool that is at least 24 bytes is large enough to hold a `std::vector<std::string>` object. Since the `std::vector` just contains pointers to allocated memory where it stores its elements, `sizeof(std::vector<std::string>)` stays constant even while the vector grows.

### Don't use `auto`

Personally, I *hate* `auto`. It obfuscates at every turn. I talk about that a bit [in my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656629/4561887). The use of `auto` is a debated topic, however. Some people really love it. And...that's one of the reasons I don't want to work with those people. :) I'd rather go program in C than fight with a C++ developer about `auto`.

Also, to see how C++ sees your code, run it through https://cppinsights.io/. I've found this tool to be *amazing* to help me better understand C++! I only recently found out about it about the time I wrote [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656629/4561887), which was just a couple months ago (Mar. 2023).

Comment: Is your answer an attempt to describe the status quo? Because the question was, and I quote, "What's stopping "auto" from inferring the type [...]?", and the only thing stopping it is the specification as is today. You seem to imply that it's a stupid wish by showing some absurd examples (reinterpret cast from int to vector?), but not only is it not stupid, it's been done by many languages (C# has target-typing and Rust has literally what OP is asking for, back-propagating target-typing).

Comment: For reference, https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/inference.html

Comment: @Blindy, I updated the top of my answer. Also, reinterpret casting from `int` to vector might be dumb, but from a memory pool of bytes to vector isn't necessarily. Memory pools are used in safety-critical systems all the time. I'm just explaining how the C++ compiler _is_, not how it should be.

Comment: @Blindy, regarding your comment, "You seem to imply that it's a stupid wish by showing some absurd examples...", I don't imply it to be a stupid wish and I never read my own answer this way nor wrote it to imply that. It's a good question. I also don't consider my examples to be absurd, I consider them to be intriguing, insightful, relevant, and useful. Again, casting an `int` to a vector doesn't make sense, but casting a memory pool, which could be represented as an array of `int`, _does_ make sense, and is _very_ relevant in my field of work: safety-critical embedded software on mcus.

Comment: @Blindy, that's a great Rust example, by the way. Thanks for pointing me to that. I now know where the "hello world" documentation is for Rust. I've now bookmarked that ["Rust By Example"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/index.html) book.

Comment: So, yes, I'm just explaining the status quo for how C++ currently works (and will probably forever work).

Comment: "yes, I'm just explaining the status quo for how C++ currently works" -- that was my problem with your answer (before the aforementioned edit): that is simply not the question. The question is *why* is the status quo so limited, and I must admit I also asked a similar-natured question about target-typing `optional<>` a while ago. C++ is just so limited in type inference for no good reason. That's also probably the reason why you hate `auto`, it's not doing even a fraction of what it should do, and half of what it does is a synonym for `template`.

Comment: Also I try to avoid telling strangers how to code, but your use of untyped memory as memory pools of C++ objects is an objectively bad practice, and while you're free to do as you wish, you probably shouldn't advise others to do the same. You are literally fighting the compiler trying to optimize your code by creating type aliases (references to the same memory from different locations with different types). If you want a vector of strings, use a vector of strings.

Comment: @Blindy, "If you want a vector of strings, use a vector of strings." That's my point too. I don't demonstrate a "good" example of memory pools here. I just teach some interesting concepts. Notice where I say, "Or, just skip the memory pool and use the proper type in the first place".

Comment: "Also I try to avoid telling strangers how to code". Sounds like you shouldn't be on Stack Overflow then, as the whole point of it is "to tell strangers how to code." That's the reason for the entire existence of the site. :) Don't read books either. They also tell strangers how to code. And heaven forbid, don't take a course in programming, those instructors do the same. Note: I'm being playful here. Please don't take this offensively. In all seriousness though, the job of answering questions and teaching and learning is to learn from strangers and teach to strangers how to code.

Answer (score 5):

The **problem** is that when using `auto` to declare a variable, the type must be deducible from the **initializer**. But there is no initializer in your *variable declaration*.

This can be seen from [Placeholder type specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be **automatically deduced from its initializer**.

---

But since you've not specified any initializer, you get the mentioned error.

Comment: Upvoted. But, adding some examples of what some valid initializers look like with `auto` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Making the return type of a function `vector<string>` doesn't necessarily mean that every vector you will use inside this function will be a vector of type string.

If you want to declare a variable using `auto` keyword, you must initialize this variable. Example: `auto x = 42; // x is inferred to be an int`

So to fix this issue, you should explicitly specify the type of vector `vec`

Comment: *Making the return type of a function vector<string> doesn't necessarily mean that every vector you will use inside this function will be a vector of type string*... but the one I'm returning has to be `std::vector<std::string>`, no?

Comment: @justanotherguy For `auto` to work, the type must be deducible from the expression used to initialize it.  The compiler doesn't look at any further context; it only looks at `auto vec;`, which does not contain enough information to determine what type you want `vec` to be.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, mind typing this out as an answer so I may accept it? :)